# Wordpress wp_remote_post cannot get body value

Tags: php, wordpress, request

i hope somebody can help wth this, we are trying to call an external auth api token generation, the call is ok, but we can get the body value, next the code we are using, i dont know why is retunr the number 1 in the body request, im trying in differents ways, but i dont know what is wrong

```
error_log("\n\n ******************************************TOKEN GENERATION");   
$url="http://*.*.*.*:7100/api/clienteExterno/login/authenticate";
$data='{"Usuario":"woocommerce","Password":"Mercaderia2021"}';
$args = array(
'headers'     => array(
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache ',
    'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
),
    'method' => 'POST', 
    "blocking" => true,
    'body' => $data,
    'timeout' => 10
); 

 $result = wp_remote_post($url, $args); 

if ( is_wp_error( $result ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $result ) != 200 || !isset( $result['body'] ) ) {
    
        $error_message = json_encode($result);
    
    error_log("\n\n ******************************************ERROR TOKEN DEVUELVEJYB" . $error_message);
                 $return = array('message' => "Error al generar token jyb");
            wp_send_json_error($return);
            wp_die(0);
}


//$responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

 
if (wp_remote_retrieve_body($result)){
    $response = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($result),false);
    //$response =json_decode($data);
        error_log("\n\n ******************************************TOKEN DEVUELVE JYB ARRAY" . print_r($response));
    
    WC()->session->set('tokenjyb', $response);      
        return  $response;
}else{
    
    WC()->session->set('tokenjyb', null);
};


return false;
```

The answer printed

```
 ([headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [cache-control] => no-cache
                [pragma] => no-cache
                [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
                [expires] => -1
                [server] => Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                [x-aspnet-version] => 4.0.30319
                [x-powered-by] => ASP.NET
                [access-control-allow-methods] => *
                [date] => Thu, 01 Jul 2021 16:44:58 GMT
                [content-length] => 217
            )

    )

[body] =>"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Indvb2NvbW1lcmNlIiwibmJmIjoxNjI1MTU3ODk4LCJleHAiOjE2MjUxNTk2OTgsImlhdCI6MTYyNTE1Nzg5OCwiaXNzIjoiKiIsImF1ZCI6IioifQ.l3sP5hYM1VZlNro3HZ_VdUACqV9CaH5UZL5mYkS73jk"
[response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 200
        [message] => OK
    )

[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[filename] => 
[http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
    (
        [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
            (
                [body] =>"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Indvb2NvbW1lcmNlIiwibmJmIjoxNjI1MTU3ODk4LCJleHAiOjE2MjUxNTk2OTgsImlhdCI6MTYyNTE1Nzg5OCwiaXNzIjoiKiIsImF1ZCI6IioifQ.l3sP5hYM1VZlNro3HZ_VdUACqV9CaH5UZL5mYkS73jk"
                [raw] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Methods: * Date: Thu, 01 Jul 2021 16:44:58 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 217 "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Indvb2NvbW1lcmNlIiwibmJmIjoxNjI1MTU3ODk4LCJleHAiOjE2MjUxNTk2OTgsImlhdCI6MTYyNTE1Nzg5OCwiaXNzIjoiKiIsImF1ZCI6IioifQ.l3sP5hYM1VZlNro3HZ_VdUACqV9CaH5UZL5mYkS73jk"
                [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                    (
                        [data:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [cache-control] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => no-cache
                                    )

                                [pragma] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => no-cache
                                    )

                                [content-type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => application/json; charset=utf-8
                                    )

                                [expires] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => -1
                                    )

                                [server] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                                    )

                                [x-aspnet-version] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 4.0.30319
                                    )

                                [x-powered-by] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => ASP.NET
                                    )

                                [access-control-allow-methods] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => *
                                    )

                                [date] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Thu, 01 Jul 2021 16:44:58 GMT
                                    )

                                [content-length] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 217
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [status_code] => 200
                [protocol_version] => 1.1
                [success] => 1
                [redirects] => 0
                [url] =>http://190.131.205.159:7100/api/clienteExterno/login/authenticate
                [history] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                    (
                        [cookies:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [filename:protected] => 
        [data] => 
        [headers] => 
        [status] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is, but I can tell that the body's value in your printed answer is a JWT.

Comment: Yes, but when i get tha value, is showing as the number 1, and not the jwt token value

Comment: You can't call `json_decode` on a JWT, you need to either parse or just store it for usage later. This is a [great library for working with JWT and PHP](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt).

Comment: Thank you so much, i will change my code

Comment: Nothin i changed  this part, but the same number one is showing
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($result);
   error_log("\n\n ******************************************TOKEN DEVUELVE JYB ARRAY" . print_r($response));

 ******************************************TOKEN DEVUELVE JYB ARRAY1
[01-Jul-2021 17:41:32 UTC] 

 ******************************************TOKN GENERADO 1

Comment: i think i know what is going on

Comment: It was solved, the value was saved with the ""